# Using Java, can I convert a human readable color name into an integer array?

Tags: java, colors

Using Java, how do I convert a human readable color name into a three-element integer array?

For example, I have a color represented by:

```
int[] RGB_COLOR = {128,25,25};
```

And I want to be able to convert the static value [`Color.BLUE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) into a three-element integer array that is similar to the one above.  Is this possible or do I have to hack my way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this...

```
Color c = Color.BLUE;
int[] RGB = { c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue() };
```

To convert a colour name to a Color you can use reflections, provided its own of the built in colours.  If you want more colours you would need to use a map.

```
public static Color colorOf(String color) {
    try {
        return (Color) Color.class.getDeclaredField(color).get(null);
    } catch(Exception notAvailable) {
        return null; // ??
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost answers my question, as it answers my int[] question but it doesn't answer how to convert the string "BLUE" into the static Color.BLUE . There is no method called 'new Color("BLUE")'.

Comment: I have added an option for built-in colours.  However you are likely to want a more extensive list of your own.  You could use a properties file for example.

Comment: Thanks to you all.  This works great for me.  All I needed was access to the default colors in the Color class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `getGreen()`, `getRed()`, `getBlue()` methods of the `Color` class

Answer (score 1):

scroll down on the doc you linked

```
Color c = //...;
int[] color = {c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue()};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get a `Color` object from a `String` would be to create a `Map<String, Color>` mapping the valid `String` color names to `Color` objects.

```
Map<String, Color> map = new HashMap<String, Color>();
map.put("BLUE", Color.BLUE);
// etc.

Color color = map.get(someString);
```

Also, I'd recomment *not* storing the RGB values in an `int[3]` unless you really need that because some 3rd party code expects it or something. Just using the `Color` class is much more appropriate in general.